# Removing last subdirectory from url with htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I am trying to remove the last directory /feed from all urls with htaccess.

/feed is added after different subdirectories of the root at different depths and my goal is to keep the entire url regardless its subdirectories except the last /feed.

I've tried different rewriterules and redirectmatches without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule in root .htaccess:

```
RedirectMatch 301 (?i)^/(.*?)/feed/?$ /$1
```

Comment: fantastic, I didn't use (?i) before. I'll look into that some more for future reference. This works perfectly though! Thanks!

Comment: Glad it worked out. `(?i)` is for ignore case match.